# Permission denied copying my own documents? (Win 7)

Tags: windows-7, vbscript

I'm using the following vbscript to back up my documents:

```
If strMessage = vbYes Then
    Dim FSO
    Dim objShell
    Dim strDesktop 
    Dim strDocuments

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    strDesktop = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    strDocuments = objShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")

    If FSO.DriveExists("H") Then
        FSO.CopyFolder strDesktop, "H:\Desktop", True
        FSO.CopyFolder strDocuments, "H:\Documents", True
    Else 
        MsgBox("Your personal folder is not mapped.  Please contact IT to have it mapped or created.")
    End if
Else
    MsgBox("You will be reminded again in 30 days")
End if
```

It works fine, except I run into a "permissions denied" error when copying My Documents.  I cannot think of any reason why I wouldn't have access to copy my own documents....is it something to do with Windows Script Host?

Comment: Why you don't have access to your documents? You're not trying to access them, your script is. I'm not sure about how Windows handles all this again, but it's the account under which your script runs under you're interested in, not "you".

Comment: I'm running the script under my own account.

Comment: Works for me. Is your documents folder redirected? Does it have locked files or files you don't have access to in it?

Comment: I have full control over all of the files and none of them are in use.  I don't believe the folder is redirected, I haven't modified it in any way.